# How to create Customized group in RPM, Fedora

Tags: fedora, rpm

Hi I am using Fedora 10 linux. I have created an rpm for my application. I can run my going to manubar and then   application under Applications----> Others--> MyApplication.

But I want my application must be located at Applications-->My Appl Folder --> MyApplication.

So how can I achieve this.

How to create Customized group in RPM, Fedora

Comment: Please supply more information: What is your .desktop file look like? What is in the "Group:" section of your rpm .spec file?

Comment: I want in Group I want to post my name. But now I have written "Applications" in Group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Do the following to create a group. actually its not group its a menu.

create a menu file (eg myapp.menu which is an xml file) put in /usr/xdg/menus